# Kill MSAccess process via batchfile

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to open MS access have a delay of about 5 seconds then close the application.

With the .bat file below I have the program opening but I can not get it to close after the delay.

```
@echo off
start /B "Access" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\OFFICE14\MSAccess.exe"
"G:\Departmental Submissions\Cardiac Rehab\Cardiac Rehab.accdb" 
wait -n 5
TASKKILL /F /IM MSAccess.exe
```

Comment: What is Access doing when it is opened? I'm assuming it's running some code that you estimate will take 5 seconds to run?

Comment: I have use this command in past  
`TASKKILL /F /fi /IM MSACCESS.EXE /T`

Answer (score 1):

the third reply   on [this](http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=238922) indicates that you have to write a startup script to close it....

```
To get the database to close you need to write a Startup function which controls
all   the events you wish to run and then use Docmd.Quit,
```

Comment: @user, could you please "accept" this as the answer?  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could use a sysinternals tool called pskill. I have a batch file that stops several processes and services for a legacy app we use. To kill MSAccess using pskill you could write START C:\SI\pskill -t msaccess.exe.